# MVC View int to boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my view I like to create a boolean base on the int values of 36 and 37. Is there a way to do this? or do I need to create two boolean? I have this if statement that I just like to use boolean vs int?

View

```
@{ 
   boolean UserTyper = Model.TypeId == 36 ? true : false
}
```

Like to do something like this?

```
 @{ 
       boolean UserTyper = Model.TypeId == 36 or 37 ? true : false
    }



 @if (UserTyper  == true) 
            {
```

Comment: `@{bool userTyper = (Model.TypeId == 36 || Model.TypeId == 37);}`? Note that the `? true : false` part is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of conditional logic usually signifies some kind of business requirement and therefore should not be done in the View:

```
class Model
{
    public bool UserType => TypeId == 36 || TypeId == 37;
}
```

View:

```
@if (Model.UserType) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check inline like this:

```
bool userTyper = (Model.TypeId == 36 || Model.TypeId == 37);
```

Or if you have a preset you want to check you could do this:

```
var checkIds = new List<int>() {36, 37};
bool userTyper = checkIds.Contains(Model.TypeId);
```

You can also shorten it if you wanted to one line:

```
bool userTyper = new List<int> { 36, 37 }.Contains(Model.TypeId)
```